# XSD validation: total digits and fraction digits

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation, fractions, altova

I have got an XSD restriction definition:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
  <xs:totalDigits value="15"/>
  <xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

the following XML fragment is considered to be valid by my XSD processor (namely, Altova XML Spy):

```
<MySum>123456789012345.00</MySum>
```

although it has a total of 17 digits.
However,

```
<MySum>123456789012345.01</MySum>
```

is considered to be invalid.

Is the processor's behaviour correct? I thought it should not try to round the values

Comment: Consider adding a pattern if you have specific requirements, something like [0-9]{17}\.[0-9]{2}

Comment: Yeah, but in our case the schema is created externally and we cannot change it. The question was if the behaviour of the  validating software was correct or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-fractionDigits
that "adding ... leading zero digits or trailing fractional zero digits is still permitted". So the behaviour seems to be correct.